# Как убрать добавленный класс при потере фокуса

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить (или правильно переделать) код, чтобы при потере фокуса с элемента снимался добавленный класс.

```
$(".flat-field" )
.focus(
    function() {
        $( this ).addClass('flat-field-focus');
    }
)
```

Пробовал через mouseleave, но он частично решил мою проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам поможет событие [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)

```
$(".flat-field" )
.blur(
    function() {
        $( this ).removeClass('flat-field-focus');
    }
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Два в одном:

```
$('.flat-field').on('focus blur', function (evt) {
   $(this).toggleClass('flat-field-focus', evt.type === 'focus');
});
```